# creating a file with uniques string per line in command line

Tags: parsing, unix, awk

I am trying to create a file (using AWK, but do not mind switching if another command is easier) that has a unique string in each line (183745 lines total). I am trying to make a file as such:

```
 line1
 line2
 line3
 ....
 line183745
```

With poor knowledge of AWK, and failure to find a similar example, I have unsuccessfully tried (with 10 lines for this example):

```
awk '{ i = 1; while (i < 10) { print "line$i \n"}; i++ }'
```

And this leads to no error or output. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Why make it complicate?

```
seq -f "line%06g" 3
line000001
line000002
line000003
```

```
seq -f "line%06g" 183745 >newfile
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to put this in a BEGIN block, as you're not processing any lines of input.

```
awk 'BEGIN { i = 1 ; while (i <= 10) { print "line"i ; i++ } }'
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` acts like a filter by default. In your case, it's simply blocking on input. Unblock it by explicitly not having input, for example.

```
awk '...' </dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

If I do this, I would do it with `seq` or in `vim`.

but since others have already posted `seq` and classic `awk` solution, I would add another `awk` solution for fun.

A very "useful" command **`yes`** could help us:

```
awk '$0="line"NR;NR==183745{exit}'
```

test with 1-10, for example:

```
kent$ yes|awk '$0="line"NR;NR==10{exit}'
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
```